# Null pointer access: The variable context can only be null at this location

Tags: android

i keep getting this error on line but if i remove the null i get errors on context telling me to initialize variable..

```
nm = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
```

**this is my code**

```
            public void createDialog(Enter_med enter_med) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        Context context = null;

        NotificationManager nm;
          nm = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);        
          CharSequence from = "VIPUL";
          CharSequence message = "Crazy About Android...";
          PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0,
            new Intent(), 0);
          Notification notif = new Notification(R.drawable.ic_launcher,
            "Crazy About Android...", System.currentTimeMillis());
          notif.setLatestEventInfo(context, from, message, contentIntent);
          nm.notify(1, notif);
    }
```

Comment: the error means that context is null

Comment: and `Context context = null;` kind of explains it

Comment: you define context as null two rows above the row where you get the error.

Comment: if i remove null i get errors on context

Comment: do you understand why it gives the error on context?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try and initiate the `context` in your `onCreate`.

```
Context context;
public void onCreate(...){
   ...
   context = this;
   ...
}
```

And then you use it with `nm = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);`

Your problem is that you need to initiate it with the activity context, not `null`

Comment: You are going to leak the activity this way. The correct solution would be `context = getApplicationContext();`.

Answer (score 0):

You are initializing context with null, and then using it..
You should initialaize it with the activity context